# What Stochastic Classifiers are available

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Assume we have these inputs and output data:

1,1 -> 1

1,1 -> 1

1,1 -> 1

1,1 -> 0

1,0 -> 0

0,1 -> 1

0,0 -> 0

Is there any type of classifier that we can train with above data and when we give (1,1) as input, 75% of the time it gives out 1 and 25% of the time gives 0? (and 100% for the rest of the cases since they do not have alternatives).

I am only aware of Boltzmann machine (a stochastic neural network). How about classifiers other than Nnet?

Comment: I don't understand the negative votes? If you don't like the question just don't answer it! It is a legit question and it matches the rules of stackoverflow.

Comment: SO is about programming issues, this question should rather be posted at cross validated. This seems to be a reason for downvotes

Answer (score 2):

In fact any classifier, that can output class probabilities (including Naive Bayes, NN, SVM) can work this way. In most cases you simply select class which maximizes the conditional probability

```
P(c|x)
```

In your case, simply select class according to probability distribution

```
c ~ P(c|x)
```

so for example, you train SVM with probabilistic outputs, and get that for a given input `x_1` you have

```
P(1|x_1) = 0.75; P(0|x_1) = 0.25
```

And simply return `1` with `75%` chance

Comment: Determinisistic vs stochastic.

Comment: A trained network will always produce the same class for an input. A stochastic classifier won't

Comment: that's up to you to decide, there is nothing "inherit" about a network or (almost) any ML model to act like you describe. Being stochastic is not a property of a "model class", it is how you use it.